# how to have a nested navigator after some content with react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I know with react navigation I'm only supposed to render 1 navigator explicitly and other navigators should just be routes on that navigator per this warning:

> You should only render one navigator explicitly in your app, and other navigators should be rendered by including them in that navigator

and after looking at a few github issues everyone says whatever you're trying to do can be done by following what that warning says. But every time I build a react native app I come across this situation, a navigator that needs to show up after some content in the main navigator. To illustrate, I made a basic design of what I need at the bottom of the question.

how would I build something like this? My initial thought is to have a primary stack navigator with some pages in it. One of the pages would have an explicitly rendered tab navigator that people can use to swipe right/left on that specific page under some content at the top.

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  home: HomeScreen
});

const TabNavigator = createTabNav({ ... });

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        ... some content here
        <TabNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

if this is the wrong way to do, what would be the right way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the correct way to do this, per this page: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html would be the following:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  home: HomeScreen
});

const TabNavigator = createTabNav({ ... });

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static router = TabNavigator.router;

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        ... some content here
        <TabNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

basically, assigning a static router variable on the screen that renders a child navigator, and passing down the navigation prop from the screen to the child navigator